# is it possible to fill as many next cells as the value in other cell is in Excel?

Tags: excel

[image]

So in my case, is it possible to fill next 8 cells with green fill automaticaly?

Comment: In VBA it's quite easy to do, would that be OK? trigger how? And you meant 5 cells changed, right?

Comment: Conditional formatting does that. What have you tried?

Comment: type 5 > 8 cells need to be highlighted.. If I type other number, how many cells will be highlighted ?